# Android webview "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In my android program I got a webview and need to set values to the webview elements (textareas, checkboxes etc) dynamically. i have a javascript method which receives values from the program and perform string operations and stores the values to the correct element. But i get this error always... kinda stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

I successfully executed the script in the w3schools TryIt Editor, but not working in the program!

```
final WebView webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
webView.setLayoutParams(params);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new android.webkit.WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadData("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>"+ questionsArray[questionIndex] +"</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
webView.addJavascriptInterface(javaScriptInterface, "HtmlViewer");
scrolRootLayout.addView(surveyWebView);
```

And my Javascript method to set values for the textareas in the webView

```
function myFunction(var_)
{
    var str = var_.replace("-!!!-","");
    var pipeSplitedArray = str.split("||");

    for(var i=0; i<pipeSplitedArray.length-1; i++) {  

        if(pipeSplitedArray[i].indexOf("-!@!-") == -1) {

            var queArray = new Array();
            queArray =pipeSplitedArray[i].split("-@!@-");

            if(document.getElementsByName(queArray[0]))
                 document.getElementsByName(queArray[0]).item(0).innerHTML=queArray[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Values are passed on onPageFinished loading..

```
    private class WebChromeClient extends WebViewClient {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                     view.loadUrl(url);
                     return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                     String script = "javascript:function myFunction(var_) { var pipeSplitedArray = var_.split(\"\\|\\|\"); for(var i=0; i<pipeSplitedArray.length-1; i++) {  if(pipeSplitedArray[i].indexOf(\"-!@!-\") == -1) { var queArray = new Array(); queArray =pipeSplitedArray[i].split(\"-@!@-\"); if(document.getElementsByName(queArray[0])) document.getElementsByName(queArray[0]).item(0).innerHTML=queArray[1]; } } }";
                     view.loadUrl(script);
                     view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.injectIntoWebView(myFunction("+answerString+"));");
                }
            }
```

The HTML content loaded in the webView, questionsArray[questionIndex] is

```
<div class="newmain5 norma12" style="position:relative;width:320px;"> Enter your name :</div>
<div class="newmain6" style="position:relative;width:275px;left:10px;">
<textarea name="69_206"  id="1" rows="5" cols="30" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666666; width:260px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; background-color:#EBEBEB;" />
</textarea>
</div>
```

String passed on onPageFinished:

```
69_206-@!@-MyName||
```

The Error i get all time while running my application is

```
11-23 14:46:59.786: I/chromium(2763): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL", source:  (1)
```

I tried running the script in the w3schools Tryit Editor and the script is successfully executed, but never in the android application.. whats my mistake? Would be great if you can help!!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what should be need to replace string by javascript.

Comment: str.replace("/-!!!-/","") check this

Comment: what you want to replace empty either null

Comment: tried replacing all string replace like you said! but no joy!!

Comment: should try this str.replace("/-!!!-/"," ") or str.replace("-!!!-"," ")

Comment: i think this work str.replace(-!!!-," ") or str.replace(-!!!-,"")

Comment: try this also str.replace(/-!!!-/g," ") or str.replace(/-!!!-/g,"")

Comment: i just deleted that line of code, that replace is performed in the program itself.. the result will be 69_206-@!@-MyName||

same error!!

Comment: MyName is the text to the textarea!

Comment: check your split method

Comment: will report back! is there any issue with webview or loadUrl ??

Comment: No, the problems in your javascript function. what you expected output

Comment: well one sec..

im passing my answerString like this ---->
 javascript:function myFunction('"+answerString+"') { var str = var_.replace(\"-!!!-\",\"\");..........................

and js method like this->

function myFunction(var_)
{
    var str = var_.replace("-!!!-","");
.................

how the answerString is assigned to var_ ???????????? :O

Comment: Hi, please use this for replace var_.replace(/-!!!-/g,"")

Comment: @iDev please check the edit... 

Error - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" is removed. 
but the current error is “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL” :O :|
any suggestions????

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the Error. You need to put the String value in quotes while passing as parameter.

**Wrong**

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.injectIntoWebView(myFunction("+answerString+"));");
```

**Correct**

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.injectIntoWebView(myFunction('"+answerString+"'));");
```

The value should be in quotes, check `myFunction('69_206-@!@-MyName||')`

Answer (score 1):

Check your JavaScript file

if you have Wrong syntax of relational operator in if statement.

change `=> to >= and =< to <=`

```
$('#search').bind('keydown', function() {
    tmp = Number(event.keyCode);
    if ((tmp  <= "48" && tmp  >= "90") || (tmp  <= "96" && tmp  >= "111") || (tmp  <= "186" && tmp  >= "222")) {
        showSearching();
    }
});​
```

Other check this your code:

If you need to make sure that the string is not just a bunch of empty spaces (I'm assuming this is for form validation) you need to do a replace on the spaces.

```
str.replace(/-!!!-/g,"")
```

Comment: no, my Javascript method does not have the specified operators!! The Javascript code is provided above! :|