# Android: Remote webview debugging for API level below 19?

Tags: android, webview

I understand that remote debugging via `chrome://inspect` was added in API level 19 for webviews. However, I'm developing an app which supports devices 17+. Its just that on API 19, I get `02-28 00:31:16.569 12332-12332/package E/Web Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at null:1` which is not very helpful.

Is there any other way to debug android webview for API < 19? At least can I see JS console?

Comment: Did u read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159855/android-webview-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)?

Comment: @keshav but in my case the app works fine for api >= 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation is to the the JavaScript console API for below Android 4.4

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

But if you want something less directly manual see:

See: [How can I debug javascript on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android)

and specifically look for things like Cordova/Weinre or other JavaScript based debugging framework.